# Connection String Decryption First 8 character has not decrypting true

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, character-encoding, connection-string

I have connection string encryption/decryption code in c#.net. But when i decrypt the encrypted string just first 8 character decrypting wrong the others are true. What can be the problem ? 
I used that codes without Initialization Vector.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649224.aspx

İts the DecryptTransformer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Encryption
{
    internal class DecryptTransformer
    {
        private EncryptionAlgorithm algorithmID;
      private byte[] initVec;
        internal DecryptTransformer(EncryptionAlgorithm deCryptId)
        {
            algorithmID = deCryptId;
        }
        internal ICryptoTransform GetCryptoServiceProvider(byte[] bytesKey/*,
byte[] initVec*/)
        {
            // Pick the provider.
            switch (algorithmID)
            {
                case EncryptionAlgorithm.Des:
                    {
                        DES des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                        des.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                        des.Key = bytesKey;
                     //   des.IV = initVec;
                        return des.CreateDecryptor();
                    }
                case EncryptionAlgorithm.TripleDes:
                    {
                        TripleDES des3 = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
                        des3.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                        return des3.CreateDecryptor(bytesKey, initVec);
                    }
                case EncryptionAlgorithm.Rc2:
                    {
                        RC2 rc2 = new RC2CryptoServiceProvider();
                        rc2.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                        return rc2.CreateDecryptor(bytesKey, initVec);
                    }
                case EncryptionAlgorithm.Rijndael:
                    {
                        Rijndael rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
                        rijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                        return rijndael.CreateDecryptor(bytesKey, initVec);
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        throw new CryptographicException("Algorithm ID '" +
                          algorithmID +
                                                         "' not supported.");
                    }
            }
        } //end GetCryptoServiceProvider
        internal byte[] IV
        {
            set { initVec = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

its Decryptor.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace Encryption
{
    public class Decryptor
    {
        private DecryptTransformer transformer;
        private byte[] initVec;
        public Decryptor(EncryptionAlgorithm algId)
        {
            transformer = new DecryptTransformer(algId);
        }
     public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] bytesData, byte[] bytesKey/*,
 byte[] initVec*/)
{
  //Set up the memory stream for the decrypted data.
  MemoryStream memStreamDecryptedData = new MemoryStream();

  //Pass in the initialization vector.
  //transformer.IV = initVec;
  ICryptoTransform transform = 
    transformer.GetCryptoServiceProvider(bytesKey/*,initVec*/);
  CryptoStream decStream = new CryptoStream(memStreamDecryptedData,
                                            transform,
                                            CryptoStreamMode.Write);
  try
  {
    decStream.Write(bytesData, 0, bytesData.Length);
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception("Error while writing encrypted data to the stream: \n" 
                        + ex.Message);
  }
  decStream.FlushFinalBlock();
  decStream.Close();
  // Send the data back.
  return memStreamDecryptedData.ToArray();
} //end Decrypt
        public byte[] IV
        {
            set { initVec = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

and Form part

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Encryption;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace datareg
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                // Create the encryptor object, specifying 3DES as the
                // encryption algorithm
                Encryptor enc = new Encryptor(EncryptionAlgorithm.TripleDes);
                // Get the connection string as a byte array
                byte[] plainText =
                  Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtConnectionString.Text);
                byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtKey.Text);

                // Perform the encryption
                byte[] cipherText = enc.Encrypt(plainText, key/*,enc.IV*/);
                // Store the intialization vector, as this will be required
                // for decryption
              //  txtInitializationVector.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(enc.IV);

                // Display the encrypted string
                txtEncryptedString.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception encrypting: " + ex.Message,
                                "Encryption ");
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Set up the Decryptor object
                Decryptor dec = new Decryptor(EncryptionAlgorithm.TripleDes);

                // Set the Initialization Vector
                dec.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtInitializationVector.Text);

                byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtKey.Text);
                // Perform the decryption
               byte[] plainText = dec.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(
                                                txtEncryptedString.Text),
                                                key/*,dec.IV*/);

                // Display the decrypted string.
                txtDecryptedString.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plainText);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception decrypting. " + ex.Message,
                                "Encryption Test Harness");
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create registry key and named values
RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software",true);
rk = rk.CreateSubKey("TestApplication");

// Write encrypted string, initialization vector and key to the registry
rk.SetValue("connectionString",txtEncryptedString.Text);
//rk.SetValue("initVector",
        //   Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtInitializationVector.Text));
rk.SetValue("key", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtKey.Text));
MessageBox.Show("The data has been successfully written to the registry");
        }
    }
}
```

[its the ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3RWZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. Solution is simple, In your encrypt & Decrypt method use the same IV parameter value to get the exact result. /*,dec.IV*/   * /*,enc.IV*/

```
byte[] cipherText = enc.Encrypt(plainText, key ,Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345678"));
```

This IV is used for achieve a unique encryption value in every encryption. IV is auto generated if not specified. in this case, you should ignore the first 8 digits.